# Change children class with parent onClick in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple parent components and within each parent component are nested children components. I'd like to have the class in the nested childrens' component change when a link in that parent component is clicked (a show/hide toggle type thing). I'm guessing this can be done by setting and changing state in the parent component on the click, but am not sure. Is this the correct way to handle this?

Is it usually best practice to hold state in the root component (I should note that the parent component explained above is ***not*** the root).

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the higher up in your component hierarchy you can push state, the better. Then as the state changes in your parent/root component, new props will trickle down to child components. This makes your child components a lot simpler because they don't have to manage as much of their own state, if any.

In your case, you're exactly right. Handle the click event in your parent which will change your state, then render your child component with the correct className based on that state.

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <div {...this.props}></div>;
    }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
    handleLinkClick: function (e) {
        this.setState({toggle: !this.state.toggle});
    },

    render: function () {
        return <Child className={this.state.toggle ? 'yes' : 'no'} />;
    }
});
```